# How to use `request` in the custom fields of `list_display` in Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-request

I need to keep information about filtering and searching in `Django` admin `change` page.

So when user filters by `"?away_team__id__exact=267821"`, I need to append this query to `change page` url.

Let's say we filtered objects by query above. This is the url of change list:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/matches/match/?away_team__id__exact=267821
```

I want to make `change` field which redirects user to `change` page of the current object and appends query to the url so instead:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/matches/match/2009/change/
```

The url will be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/matches/match/2009/change/?away_team__id__exact=267821
```

The problem is that I couldn't access request in the custom field method. I tried to do it using template language but without success, I get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/matches/match/1996/change/?{{%20request.GET.urlencode%20}}
```

This is the method:

```
def change(self,obj):
    return mark_safe(f"""<a class="changelink" href="{reverse("admin:matches_match_change",args=(obj.pk,))}"""+"?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}\""+"><span class='icon'>Zmeniť</span></a>")
```

Do you know how to do that?

**EDIT**

This is because I need to create a `NEXT` and `PREVIOUS` buttons in `change` object page so user can step directly to the next object.

Comment: You can extract the querystring from the change list in the change view itself from `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` in order to process that information.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Overriding change view is a good idea, I didn't know that there is change_view function in admin. Thanks

Comment: @schwobaseggl Hm, but when user clicks first time on NEXT button, the HTTP_REFERER will be worthless...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just store the current request on the admin instance in the change list view to make it available to subsequent methods:

```
class YourAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        return super().changelist_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def change(self, obj):
        request = getattr(self, 'request', None)
        if request:
           # use request.GET to construct the link
```

Comment: This was helpful when I wanted a custom field that includes a link to the change_form for the instance (including preserving the list filter parameters) but doesn't make the whole field into a link (i.e. including it in `list_display_links` isn't ideal).  I used the above and then used `self.get_preserved_filters(request)` to get the querystring for the change form URL.  e.g. `link = "<a href='{}?{}'>Link</a>".format(obj.get_change_url(), self.get_preserved_filters(request))`. Then the custom field function returns `link + "Whatever you want not in the link"`.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a mixin for extending AdminModels for accessing to the request parameters:

```
class RequestParameters_AdminMixin(object):
    """adds the request GET parameters in AdminModel variable request_parameters""" 
    request_parameters={}

    def changelist_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request_parameters = request.GET
        return super().changelist_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Use:
class TaskModelAdmin(RequestParameters_AdminMixin, original_TaskModelAdmin):
def column_name(self, obj):
if 'is_maintask' in self.request_parameters:
...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request` in the custom fields of [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) by overriding [get_list_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display) as shown below. *The example below gets the current user's first and last names in `test1` and `test2` respectively and you can see [the original code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1088C1-L1093C33) of `get_list_display()` in GitHub:

```py
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('test1', 'test2')

    def (self, request):
        self.request = request # Set `request`
        return self.list_display

    def test1(self, obj):
        return self.request.user.first_name

    def test2(self, obj):
        return self.request.user.last_name
```